# Shooting function in pygame w/ 2 Players

Tags: collision-detection, pygame

I'm trying to program a shooting function in my game using pygame. Process:

- Player one will press 'Space' and shoot their type of projectile
- Player two would press 'E' and shoot their type of projectile
- Player one's projectile would collide with player two but not player one (and vice versa).

I'm not sure how to code this function properly. Here's my code so far:

```
Initalize
import pygame, math
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
#Creating sprites

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):

        super().__init__()
        #Config
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        # Draw
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])

        # Fetch
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def right(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
    def left(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
    def up(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
    def down(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels

pygame.init()
# Config
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
BLUE = ( 43, 255, 230)
ORANGE = ( 255, 170, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

SCREENWIDTH = 400
SCREENHEIGHT = 500

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Squares Fight")

group1 = pygame.sprite.Group()

player1 = Player(BLUE, 50, 50)
player2 = Player(ORANGE, 50, 50)
player1.rect.x = 5
player1.rect.y = 5
player2.rect.x = 345
player2.rect.y = 445

group1.add(player1, player2)

loop = True
startend = False
startanew = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("berlinsansfb", 72)
text = font.render("Fight!", True, WHITE)

# Game Loop
while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        loop = False

        #Logic
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                player1.left(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player1.right(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                player1.up(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                player1.down(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                player2.left(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                player2.right(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
               player2.up(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
               player2.down(3)

    collision = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player1, player2)
    if collision == True:
            group1.remove(player1, player2)
            startend = True
    group1.update()
    if startend == True:
            pygame.display.set_caption("They destroyed eachother! Press space to do it again")
            startanew = True
    if startanew == True and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            group1.add(player1, player2)
            pygame.display.set_caption("Squares Fight")
            startend = False
    # Drawing
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(text,
                (200 - text.get_width() // 2, 240 - text.get_height() // 2))
    group1.draw(screen)

    # Closing
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    #Indentation isnt right because how i needed to format this
 pygame.quit()
```

What else do I need to add to accomplish this task?

Comment: you could create `Group()` for player1's projectiles and use it with player2 to check collision. BTW: you could move some line of code inside class `Player` to make main loop smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle multiple objects that do the same thing (such as a bullet) in Pygame is by using groups. Groups are an efficient way to run the same code for a group of objects. For example:

```
class Bullet():
    def move(self):
        self.x += 1

bullet1 = Bullet()
bullet2 = Bullet()
bullet3 = Bullet()

bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group() #Make new group
bullet_group.add(bullet1, bullet2, bullet3) #Add objects to group

bullet_group.move() #Execute move() method for all objects in group
```

So let's say you wanted to make bullets from Player 2 only hit Player 1. First of all, the best way to make two different types of bullets that will move the same way is to make a parent class, **BulletParent**. Then, to get proper collisions you would most likely want to make the **BulletParent** class a child of the **pygame.sprite.Sprite** class.

```
class BulletParent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

Then you can make some kind of **move()** method inside the **BulletParent** class to move the bullet.

```
class BulletParent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.direction = direction

    def move(self):
        #add moving code here
        pass
```

Now, you can make two child classes of the **BulletParent** class, let's say **Bullet1** (for Player 1) and **Bullet2** (for Player 2). This is important because we need a way to know which bullet belongs to which player. Once you have made those classes, you need to check if each player has pressed their shoot button. Let's make one function to check key presses and make the **bullet1_group** and **bullet2_group**:

```
bullet1_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet2_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

def check_keys():
    keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()

    #Arrows keys and WASD presses

    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bullet1 = Bullet1(player1.direction) #may need to add direction variable for player1
        bullet1_group.add(bullet1)

    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        bullet2 = Bullet2(player2.direction) #may need to add direction variable for player2
        bullet2_group.add(bullet2)
```

This will make new bullets every time one of the shoot keys is pressed. Now we can make a function that returns if Player 1 is hit and make another to do the same for Player 2. We can use the **pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()** function to see if anything has collided with our players. It will return a Sprite if anything has collided and None if not.

```
def player1_hit():
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player1, bullet2_group)
    if collide == None: return False
    else: return True

def player2_hit():
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player2, bullet1_group)
    if collide == None: return False
    else: return True
```

We can make a function that moves both bullet groups:

```
def move_bullets():
    bullet1_group.move()
    bullet2_group.move()
```

Finally, you can add the **check_keys** and **move_bullets**functions to the main loop, and add some logic to use with the **player1_hit** and **player2_hit** functions.

Hope this helped and I hope you continue programming no matter the problem!